# Why does Swift need to initialized subclass's property before super.init()

Tags: swift

Here was the question, I want to find out how does init work, and where does the subclass's property store

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, to exemplify one of the reasons, let's say you have the following class definitions:

```swift
class Base {
    init() {
        sayHello()
    }

    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello from base")
    }
}

class Derived: Base {
    let name: String

    override init() {
        // no initialization of own properties, just call super()
        super.init()
    }

    override func sayHello() {
        print("Hello from \(name)")
    }
}
```

Basically, the initialized of the base class calls `sayHello`, a method which is overwritten in the child class. Now, calling `super.init()` results in the overriden method being called, which in turn needs to use the `name` property, which is not initialized a this point.

The requirement to have all subclass storage initialized before calling `super.init` is to ensure object validity before any possible actions are called on it.